# Invalid Declaration Syntax in a struct

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I'm working in C and getting the following error:

```
*** ERROR C074 IN LINE 78 OF ..\..\..\libraries\mchpstack_base\arp.c : Invalid declaration syntax
```

The relevant portion of code is:

```
typedef struct _ARP_PACKET
{
    WORD        HardwareType;
    WORD        Protocol;
    BYTE        MACAddrLen;
    BYTE        ProtocolLen;
    WORD        Operation;
    MAC_ADDR2    SenderMACAddr;
    IP_ADDR     SenderIPAddr;
    MAC_ADDR2    TargetMACAddr; // This is line 78
    IP_ADDR     TargetIPAddr;
} ARP_PACKET;
```

Now MAC_ADDR2 is define elsewhere in a header file which I am sure is included in arp.c:

```
typedef struct _MAC_ADDR2
{
    BYTE v[6];
} MAC_ADDR2;
```

I'm new to C; but read over guides on creating structs, the typedef usage, and the namespace issue within C. I'm quite stuck. What is that error telling me?

Comment: Looks valid to me. Some things to try: remove line 78 and see it it has the same issue with line 76 (if it doesn't, you know MAC_ADDR2 is fine). Run just the preprocessor to verify the definition comes first and there aren't any macros mangling anything.

Comment: I wonder if `TargetMACAddr` is `#define`d elsewhere. You can try changing that member to `TestMember` and see that makes any difference.

Comment: I had tried removing line 78 before but tried it again. Still, the exact same error. I also tried changing TargetMACAddr to TestMember, still the same error. I'll look into see if I can run just the pre-processor. I'm using ST Visual Develop.

Comment: There are too many unknown elements to the question, which can only produce 'guesses' as answers which will not (generally) be useful to SO readers.  Please provide a 'Minimal, Complete and Verifiable' example. [See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ]  Most likely, doing so will reveal the answer to the question.